# Enable S3 Bucket Object level events to CloudTrail trail and forward object level events to CloudWatch log group in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I have an existing s3 bucket, say BucketName1, and I want to enable cloud trail logs for s3 object level events. Id like to forward the S3 Object level events to CloudTrail event logs through to an existing CloudWatch logs log group.

How can I achieve this with Terraform configuration alone?

I have already created my bucket using

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket1"
```

Comment: Have you created your CloudTrial trial?

Answer (score 1):

```
 resource "aws_cloudtrail" "trail1" {
  name                          = "TrailName1"
  s3_bucket_name                = aws_s3_bucket.bucket1.id

  event_selector {
    read_write_type           = "All"
    include_management_events = false

    data_resource {
      type = "AWS::S3::Object"
      values = ["${aws_s3_bucket.bucket1.arn}/"]
    }
  }

  cloud_watch_logs_group_arn = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.logGroup1.arn}:*"
  cloud_watch_logs_role_arn = aws_iam_role.role1.arn
}
```